# O arquivo.pdf não é enviado ao servidor

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, file-upload

Estou fazendo um sistema para cadastrar o nome do arquivo e algumas outras informações no banco de dados, e também subir o arquivo para o servidor, porém só é feito o cadastro o banco de dados, mas na hora de fazer o upload do arquivo para o servidor é exibido um erro:

**`Possível ataque de upload de arquivo!
New record created successfullyAqui estão mais informações de debug:Array
(
    [arquivo] => Array
        (
            [name] => .Introducao_JavaScript.pdf
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 2
            [size] => 0
        )
)`**

```
                $uploaddir = '.';
            $uploadfile = $uploaddir. basename($_FILES['arquivo']['name']);

            echo '<pre>';
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {

                echo "Arquivo válido e enviado com sucesso.\n";
            }
            else {
                echo "Possível ataque de upload de arquivo!\n";
            }
            $sql = "INSERT INTO videoaulas (videoaula, categoria_id, categoria_id_e, categoria_id_a, idade, arquivo) VALUES ('$nome', '$nvl_surdez', '$escolaridade',                               '$aquisicao', '$fx_eta', '$uploadfile')";
                    mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
                    echo "New record created successfully";                 

            echo 'Aqui estão mais informações de debug:';
            print_r($_FILES);

            print "</pre>";
```

Comment: Qual o erro? Fica mais fácil de te ajudar com a mensagem exibida

Comment: é exibida a mensagem de erro, que eu coloquei no else, o problema é esse, eu não sei como exibir o erro @DenisRudneideSouza `Possível ataque de upload de arquivo!
New record created successfullyAqui estão mais informações de debug:Array
(
    [arquivo] => Array
        (
            [name] => .Introducao_JavaScript.pdf
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 2
            [size] => 0
        )

)`

Comment: Você pode [edit] sua pergunta para adicionar mais informações

Comment: @DenisRudneideSouza , opa, desculpa, acabei de editar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você provavelmente especificou o `MAX_FILE_SIZE` no formulário HTML, e o arquivo PDF excede este tamanho, como é dito na documentação: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

> `UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE`
>
> Value: 2; The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form.

O `error => 2` é representado pela constante `UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE`, ou seja, ou você remove isto do HTML (porque este nem é o meio ideal e nem seguro de impedir arquivos grandes demais) ou você aumenta o tamanho em:

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="tamanho máximo aqui">
```

Por falar nisso seu tratamento de erro não esta bom, deveria tratar o `error` antes de usar `move_uploaded_file` e o INSERT deveria estar dentro do IF

Algo como:

```
if ($_FILES['arquivo']['error'] != 0) {
    echo 'Ocorreu um erro durante o upload';
} elseif (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {

    echo "Arquivo válido e enviado com sucesso.\n";

    $sql = "INSERT INTO videoaulas (videoaula, categoria_id, categoria_id_e, categoria_id_a, idade, arquivo) VALUES ('$nome', '$nvl_surdez', '$escolaridade',                               '$aquisicao', '$fx_eta', '$uploadfile')";
    mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    echo "New record created successfully";  
} else {
    echo "Houve uma falha ao mover o arquivo para completar o upload\n";
}
```

---

Segue os demais erros possíveis vindos de `[error] =>`:

> Lembrando 0 (zero) que é representado por `UPLOAD_ERR_OK`, indica ausência de erro no upload e outro detalhe a função `move_uploaded_file` não faz upload, o upload já foi feito na pasta temporária do sistema operacional, está função apenas move o arquivo e checa se de fato o arquivo é um upload (checa até um tipo de ataque especifico)

- `UPLOAD_ERR_OK`

  Valor: 0; não houve erro, o upload foi bem sucedido.
- `UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE`

  Valor 1; O arquivo enviado excede o limite definido na diretiva `upload_max_filesize` do `php.ini`.
- `UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE`

  Valor: 2; O arquivo excede o limite definido em `MAX_FILE_SIZE` no formulário HTML.
- `UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL`

  Valor: 3; O upload do arquivo foi feito parcialmente.
- `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE`

  Valor: 4; Nenhum arquivo foi enviado.
- `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR`

  Valor: 6; Pasta temporária ausênte. Introduzido no PHP 5.0.3.
- `UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE`

  Valor: 7; Falha em escrever o arquivo em disco. Introduzido no PHP 5.1.0.
- `UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION`

  Valor: 8; Uma extensão do PHP interrompeu o upload do arquivo. O PHP não fornece uma maneira de determinar qual extensão causou a interrupção. Examinar a lista das extensões carregadas com o `phpinfo()` pode ajudar. Introduzido no PHP 5.2.0.

Comment: obrigado por responder, mas no meu formulário está assim `<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="200000" />` , e o arquivo em questão possui 1.1MB

Comment: @JoséThomaz como eu disse na resposta, usar isto não apresenta nenhuma segurança, qualquer pessoa no lado cliente consegue burlar isto, o melhor seria bloquear no `upload_max_filesize` dentro do php.ini ou no módulo para Apache php_mod (pelo htaccess), isto se tiver o módulo instalado no apache.

Comment: caso eu retire, o value do input, funcionaria?

Comment: @JoséThomaz provavelmente sim, mas não tenho como afirmar, pode retornar outro "error", que é um dos numeros que citei acima, por isso postei eles.

Comment: funcionou, muito obrigado amigo, mas agora quando tento exibir o arquivo no próprio browser, é exibida uma mensagem falando que o arquivo está corrompido, sabe me dizer porque isso acontece?

Comment: @JoséThomaz veja a resposta, eu a editei, o tratamento do error e o INSERT deveria ser melhor da forma que adicionei.